# Angular element wrapper directive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is a code snippet we usually see in twitter boostrap forms:

```
 <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Enter Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
       <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="member.email" required >
    </div>
 </div>
```

Having lots of fields in form code gets quite noisy so I would like to use something like this in my Angular powered html:

```
<formy label-for="email" label-text="Enter Email">
      <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="member.email" required >
</formy>
```

Can this be done by directive in Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be done

```
app.directive('formy', function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            labelText: "@",
      labelFor: '@'
        },
        template : '<div class="control-group">' +
        '<label for="{{labelFor}}" class="control-label">{{labelText}}</label>' +
        '<div class="controls" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>', 
        replace: true
    };
})
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y8dynDl3njBq9zS89GXu?p=preview)